# Trimming wood floor boards for running wires under base molding

Tags: hardwood-floor, trim, baseboard, cable-management

Renovating my apartment; started with walls, removed all base molding to run RG6/Cat5e throughout rooms under new base molding.

Here's a photo looking straight down from the wall (with molding removed). There's about 1" open space (on average) between the wall and edges of wood floor boards; this is perfect for running cable/ethernet wire. Problem is around 30-40 random boards extend to the wall, blocking my wire track, and I need to trim at least 1/2 inch of those boards to hide all wires.

[image]

I tried using my jigsaw at 90 degrees, but the base plate is too wide, cutting just over 1" of wood, not to mention cutting the subfloor too. Technically, I don't need to cut off entire pieces from each board; a wedge is sufficient provided it's deep enough to accommodate both wires, so I tried numerous jig saw angles but failed to get something working. I switched to hammer and chisel, but after 5 minutes (and minimal progress), I felt like I was escaping from prison :-)

I've got one more idea to try: if I can find a thinner base plate for my jig saw (B&D BDEJS600C), I should be able to manage the cut since I'd be closer to the wall. I'm open to any *other* ideas too. Just 1/2 inch track is all I need.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool that is made perfect for this is the type of unit pictured below:

[image]

[(this picture courtesy of MyToolShed web site)](http://www.my-tool-shed.co.uk/p1086347/DeWalt_DWE314K_Oscillating_Multi_Tool_Kit_240v/product_info.html)

These oscillating multi-tools can accommodate a variety of blades that permit close cutting exactly like you need to do. Here is an example blade that is what I would use for this cutting job.

[image]

[(this picture courtesy of Lowe's web site)](http://www.lowes.com/pd/DEWALT-3-Pack-Bi-Metal-Oscillating-Tool-Blades/50219115)

These are available from many manufacturers, both AC powered and battery powered. I went for years before getting one just a year or so ago and now use it for many jobs I used to struggle with. A particularly nice feature of the unit pictured is the LED light on the front of the unit to illuminate the cut area.

Comment: These are awesome excellent for remodel work, cutting close to other surfaces. The first one I purchased took custom blades that were quite expensive, the second is a dewalt similar to the photo and it has held up quite well for 5/6 years of heavy usage and the blades are reasonably priced. +

Comment: This appears to be my answer! I watched a few videos on youtube, not being a standard saw disc, I'm not sure how that tool does its cutting, it's almost like black magic. but anyway, thank you, this should work well!

Comment: The tool post where the blade chucks up oscillates back and forth with very short strokes. With a variable speed unit like the pictured Dewalt the trigger on the handle will vary the speed of the oscillations (not the stroke travel distance). The short stroke is the reason that blades have very fine teeth.

Comment: Note that even though some blades are rated for cutting both wood and nails that nails will shorten blade life a lot. After I learned that I made a good sized investment in a whole assortment of blades (2 or more of each). So now when I have a project to do I I can dive right in and then replace worn blades after the fact.

Comment: I recently used a blade like that pictured above to cut off aluminum extrusion material. Worked very well where a particularly precise cut is not needed and was faster then hand cutting. The blade also did not gall up as may happen when cutting aluminum with a cutoff blade.